# How do I create (and use) a unix domain socket of type SOCK_SEQPACKET on an abstract address with the Java library junixsocket?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, unix-socket

I have written a client and a server in C with such a socket, works fine. Now I need to talk to the server from Java.

The library [junixsocket](https://kohlschutter.github.io/junixsocket/index.html) should allow me to do that. But how?

I can't find a relevant example in the sources or tests, and the API is somewhat overwhelming to my Java-newbie eyes.

I get the abstract address with:

```
AFUnixSocketAddress.inAbstractNamespace("my-project").
```

How to I create the `SOCK_SEQPACKET` socket? Connect to the server? Send and receive messages?

Comment: That type is used in junixsocket/junixsocket-tipc/src/main/java/org/newsclub/net/unix/tipc/AFTIPCTopologyWatcher.java

Comment: thanks. I still need to "unwrap" lines like: `this.channel = AFTIPCDatagramSocket.newInstance(AFSocketType.SOCK_SEQPACKET).getChannel();`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you anything about it. Maybe contact author?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved using the Java Native Interface (JNI) directly. It turns out JNI is rather straightforward to use, whereas junixsocket piles up a stack of abstractions I didn't need.